# ArgumentOutOfRange In List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3D Project. In this project I'm supposed to add some data to a list in a specific index number but it throws me the following error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name:
>   index

This is my code:

```
foreach (var Player in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
{
    NameList.Clear();
    if ((int)Player.CustomProperties["GameCount"] == First)
    {
        NameList.Insert(0 ,(string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Name"]);
    }
    else if ((int)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["GameCount"] == Second)
    {
        NameList.Insert(1 ,(string)Player.CustomProperties["Name"]);
    }
    else if ((int)Player.CustomProperties["GameCount"] == Third)
    {
        NameList.Insert(2,(string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Name"]);
    }
    else if ((int)Player.CustomProperties["GameCount"] == Fourth)
    {
        NameList.Insert(3, (string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Name"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post an error message, you should always include which line is throwing the exception.  If NameList is empty, which it is, you can't insert anything in those other positions.  Nothing is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Insert** method looks as this: `public void Insert (int index, T item);`.

And exception is thrown in two scenarios, as [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2) states in the part about **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**:

1. Parameter `index` is less than 0.
2. Parameter `index` is greater than `Count`.

The first option is not true about your case as you have all your indexes higher than zero. Then it means that in one of your `else if`'s you try to insert a value in position far above the number of existing elements, this causes the exception.

What I can advice you is to make some debugging and look when you have less elements. Or to use `Add` instead of `Insert`, more info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2).

**UPDATE**

As an example, when you are trying to perform

```
NameList.Insert(3, (string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Name"]);
```

you are trying to insert an element to position `3`, but if you have only **1** element in List then your insert throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you First `element(0)` no Insert but Insert second `element(1)` that argument is out of range. Example: If the program executes first:

```
NameList.Insert(2,(string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Name"]);
```

But no executes:

```
 NameList.Insert(0 ,(string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Name"]);
```